# Where can I find description of exception thrown ny Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception, error-handling

I just got this weird exception while writing directive:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22f…sed%5C%22%3A2%7D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%7B%5C%22collapsed%5C%22%3A2%7D%22%5D%5D
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js:6:453
    at g.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js:97:177)
    at g.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js:99:100)
    at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js:65:98)
    at C (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js:68:486)
    at XMLHttpRequest.t.onreadystatechange (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js:69:466)
```

where can I find information what this error mean and why it may be thrown? Is the source code the only documention for errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow that first link that NG gives you in the error.

[http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22f…sed%5C%22%3A2%7D%3B%20oldVal%3A%20%7B%5C%22collapsed%5C%22%3A2%7D%22%5D%5D](http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/%24rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22f%E2%80%A6sed%5C%22:2%7D;%20oldVal%3a%20%7B%5C%22collapsed%5C%22:2%7D%22%5D%5D)

Comment: And I would add: always use the unminified AngularJS version for development.